# How can I modify the list of configurable warnings and errors?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

In VB projects, there's a list of specific kinds of compiler errors that you can configure to be ignored or treated as warnings or errors:

[image]

Is there a way to add other error types to this list?  I've got a certain class of compiler warning that I would like to make an error instead, but it's not on the list and I can't find a way to modify this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't edit that list, but you could edit the vbproj file. The compiler warning numbers are listed in there. The  section lists the warnings that the compiler should ignore. There's also a section for Warnings that should be regarded as errors:

```
<WarningsAsErrors>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036</WarningsAsErrors>
```

You can lookup the error codes by adding BC to the start and searching the MSDN - e.g. BC41999

There's a list of the messages here: [Visual Basic Compiler Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235336%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: It's important to note as well even warnings that are not fully numeric can be added here. They just need to have a warning "Code".
I added "BC40004" to the list because I have other developers doing some bad practice and constantly producing "Variable conflicts with an existing property in the base class and should be declared shadows" to try to prevent people from doing this in the first place.